# How do you pass an environment variable from WSL into windows executable

Tags: bash, environment-variables, windows-subsystem-for-linux

From a Windows Subsystem for Linux (v1) Alpine bash terminal, I would like to set an environment variable that get's passed into a windows executable. Is there any way to do this?

example of what I was hoping would print "Hello, World!":

```sh
windows-10:~# export X=World
windows-10:~# cmd.exe /c 'echo Hello, %X%!'
Hello, %X%!
```

## See answer from Philipe below.

Here is a copy of the pertinent info from https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/wsl/interop

### Share environment variables between Windows and WSL

```
Available in Windows Insider builds 17063 and later.
```

Prior to 17063, only Windows environment variable that WSL could access was PATH (so you could launch Win32 executables from under WSL).

Starting in 17063, WSL and Windows share WSLENV, a special environment variable created to bridge Windows and Linux distros running on WSL.

Properties of WSLENV:

```
It is shared; it exists in both Windows and WSL environments.
It is a list of environment variables to share between Windows and WSL.
It can format environment variables to work well in Windows and WSL.
```

There are four flags available in WSLENV to influence how that environment variable is translated.

WSLENV flags:

```
/p - translates the path between WSL/Linux style paths and Win32 paths.
/l - indicates the environment variable is a list of paths.
/u - indicates that this environment variable should only be included when running WSL from Win32.
/w - indicates that this environment variable should only be included when running Win32 from WSL.
```

Flags can be combined as needed.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Can you try this ?

```
~$ export X=World
~$ export WSLENV=X/w
~$ cmd.exe /c 'echo Hello, %X%!'
Hello, World!
```

Comment: That's exactly what I was looking for. For more reading, see edits in my original post. Thank you!

Comment: @Philippe: Fascinating! Could you add some explanation, what is the purpose of `/w`? This unintuitive hack, which is necessary for such a simple tasks, confirms for me that I will continue using Cygwin on Windows 10 instead of their weird WSL.....

Comment: @user1934428 according to [this post about `WSLENV`](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/commandline/share-environment-vars-between-wsl-and-windows/) the `/w` means that var will only exist when executing Windows processes from bash in WSL:

"The value should only be included when invoking Win32 from WSL"

Comment: How do I use the variable inside things like command prompts on the windows side? I have no use for the cmd.exe command from inside linux...

Comment: @JasminParent That seems to be a different question, please post a new one.